# ADB server didn't ack, already bound to tcp:5037 (after kill & restart)

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, adb, android-virtual-device

I've been setting up android-studio on my arch-linux install. I'm new to android development so this has been an exploratory process.

The problem I'm having is that I cannot get the AVD emulator to run. Looking at the log on the stdout, I get the error:

```
[  37311]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use 
[  37339]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - '/home/parma/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary 
[  37341]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - ADB server didn't ACK 
[  37341]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - * failed to start daemon * 
[  37341]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Now when I run this manually at this point, I get the same response.

I check to see what's bound to that port

```
$ ss -lpn | grep 5037
tcp    LISTEN     0      4      127.0.0.1:5037                  *:*                   users:(("adb",pid=22346,fd=7))

$ ps -aux | grep adb                                     
parma    22346  0.0  0.0 167428  1932 ?        Ssl  11:04   0:00 adb -L tcp:5037 fork-server server --reply-fd 4
parma    22668  0.0  0.0  10788  2216 pts/0    R+   11:13   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn adb
```

It appears adb is already running.

First I try:

```
$ adb kill-server 
* server not running *
```

And so I decide to just kill the process.

```
$ kill 22346
$ ps -aux | grep adb                                    
parma    23612  0.0  0.0  10788  2088 pts/0    S+   11:32   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn adb
$ ss -lpn | grep 5037
```

From here two different things happen depending on whether I attempt to start the ADB server manually, or if I attempt to start it by running the AVD emulator from the IDE.

I start it manually:

```
$ adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ ss -lpn | grep 5037                                    
tcp    LISTEN     0      4      127.0.0.1:5037                  *:*                   users:(("adb",pid=23685,fd=6))
```

And when I attempt to start the AVD I get the same error output I first posted at the top of this post.

I kill this process once more and I attempt to start the AVD after I have confirmed adb or no other process is running on port 5037

When I run this nothing happens. The IDE shows the same loading bar it displays when it fails however there is no error output this time.

I check to see if it's running, I see that is so I check what spawned the process:

```
$ ps -faux
...
parma     8953  0.0  0.4 603036 38756 ?        Rsl  Apr04   0:25  \_ /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
parma     8959  0.0  0.0  43612  6140 pts/0    Ss   Apr04   0:00  |   \_ zsh
parma    24021  0.0  0.0  41988  4336 pts/0    R+   11:45   0:00  |   |   \_ ps -faux
parma     9375  0.0  0.0  43480  5956 pts/1    Ss   Apr04   0:00  |   \_ zsh
parma    10915  0.0  0.0  13716  3116 pts/1    S+   Apr04   0:00  |       \_ /bin/sh /usr/bin/android-studio
parma    10967  0.2  9.4 5183808 763400 pts/1  Sl+  Apr04   2:40  |           \_ /home/android-studio/bin/../jre/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/android-studio/bin/../lib/boot.jar -classpath 
parma    10994  0.0  0.0   5180  2204 pts/1    S+   Apr04   0:00  |               \_ /home/android-studio/bin/fsnotifier64
parma    23842  0.0  0.0 167700  3768 ?        Ssl  11:42   0:00  \_ adb -L tcp:5037 fork-server server --reply-fd 4
...
```

It appears android-studio did start the server but something has went wrong. Of course, if I attempt to run it once more then I get the familiar "adb start-server failed... ADB server didn't ACK"

I'm completely at odds to diagnose this further. I'm hoping someone can provide me with some pointers to a solution.

I'm not using genymotion (since I've seen it come up a lot in solutions) - everything is completely stock.

As far as I can see, I appear to have only one SDK installed.

One other bit of strange behaviour I noticed when I happened to run one command which I think I think I'll mention.

After I have killed any process on 5037:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
** daemon still not running
error: cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037: Connection refused
```

I'm not sure what this implies but it seems interesting.

Thanks

Comment: May you run `which adb` and confirm that Android Studio is not using its own SDK?